# Will Visual Studio 2010 support Sharepoint 2007 development?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I noticed in VS2010 beta 2 that all the templates are for Sharepoint 2010 ONLY.

Is this true ?

If so, will the VSeWSS 1.3 work with VS2010 atleast?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Connect/Social - NOT SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember the session here at SharePoint Las Vegas conference, the new and cool Visual Studio 2010 stuff will only be available for SharePoint 2010... sorry...

You will probably still be able to do some hacks and move stuff from new VS to old SharePoint, but new features are not backward compatible.

Comment: thats a shame.. strange they are only making tools for a product that isnt even out yet.

I hope I can get the IT people here to upgrade so I can use the fancy tools.. 

I wonder if maybe some of the stuff I can make for 2010 and somehow copy the .cab to a 2007 site

Comment: @previous commenter:  VS2010 isnt out either, both the product and dev tools are in beta and have a linked release cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The final VSeWSS 1.3 release was to have been delayed by Microsoft until December 2009... I haven't checked on the final status of that. However, the new VS10 projects include import routines so that you can import old VSeWSS projects to VS10 format.

**Edit:**
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/9afcff83-dbbf-450e-a5bd-78728d991276

Quote: "Visual Studio 2010 has built in tools for SharePoint 2010 and for SharePoint 2007. But the SharePoint 2007 tools are limited to the same workflow tools that were available in Visual Studio 2008 out of the box. The VSeWSS tools are not directly included in Visual Studio 2010 and the VSeWSS release doesn't work with Visual Studio 2010, only with Visual Studio 2008."

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect VSeWSS 1.3 to work with VS2010, but you're probably better off using [STSDev](http://stsdev.codeplex.com) or [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) for 2007 development anyway, which could probably be made to work with VS2010 if they don't already.