# How to convert an ASPX.net application to WebPart in Sharepoint2007?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm starting with Sharepoint.

I have a simple C# application using a database.

I want to show it in Sharepoint2007, and my boss told me that I have to do it with a WebPart, but I've been looking for information and I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2007 web parts are difficult to build because you need to programmatically build up the presentation layer in your code.

You should definitely use [Smart Part](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/) as this allows you to develop Web parts like they are user controls in a conventional .Net application.

You should also read up on Sharepoint patterns and practices as it is fairly different in certain aspects.

Comment: It would be helpful if the person who marked my answer down could explain why. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I marked your answer up (i'm not the guy who marked it down). Smart part is a good advice ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the backup. Smart Part is the only way to build webparts at the very least. SP2010 is a lot better in this regard and there's no need

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use (see link below) to show data from the DB.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/01/26/data-view-web-part-to-view-data-from-non-sharepoint-database-adventure-works.aspx

However if you want more adaptability and the feeling that you know what your doing(I guess your a developer with some knowledge of c#)

You would possibly be best off going down the coding route. I always say work smart not hard!

Get some tools to make your job easier. WSP.builder for one(Codeplex) and start with something very simple. People say theres not much use in the hello world but it's a great place to start when learning how to deploy, Debug your first sharepoint web part.

What i would advise is.

Read up on how to use WSP builder. This will help you build your Sharepoint projects with the required structure.

You will want to use visual web part feature within wsp builder for this.

Once you know how to deploy this, Should come with reading around wsp builder! you should be well on your way to getting your web part done.

If you ever find it hard keep at it SharePoint can be a tempramental beast! Theres a wealth of knowledge on google exploit it!(Work smart not hard;))

Also if you have your own development area back it up! If it breaks you don't want to have to rebuild it i learnt the hard way!

Hope this helps

Comment: @Luis: the question specifically asks about SharePoint 2007. Visual Studio 2010 is not a good option. For more information, see [Will Visual Studio 2010 support Sharepoint 2007 development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603666/will-visual-studio-2010-support-sharepoint-2007-development).

Comment: @Rich Bennema Who's mentioned VS2010?

Comment: Someone named Luis who must have removed the comment. The comment said something along the lines that WSP was deprecated and VS 2010 should be used instead. And, while true for SharePoint 2010, that is not the case for SharePoint 2007.